# Using Webkit to create Skinable custom windows on OSX

Tags: cocoa, webkit, skinning, skin

There are tutorials for using a webkit view inside a cocoa application to achieve skinnable contents, but what would I do if I wanted to use webkit to create custom, skinnable *windows*?

Examples would be dashboard widgets, or 
[BowTie](http://bowtieapp.com/)

Beware, I'm a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried it, but I think you'd just set a WebView as the content view of a transparent borderless window, and tell the WebView not to draw a background. That way, the content of the WebView would define the window boundary.

You create a borderless window by passing NSBorderlessWindowMask to the -initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer: method of NSWindow, and you can set its background to transparent by calling [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]].

You'd have to handle dragging of the window etc yourself. It will probably get a bit messy.

To be honest, it's not something I'd attempt as a first Cocoa project.

Comment: yeah, I'm aware that it's over my head, the plan is to collect info for better times. And it's nice where (or what) to look (for). So thanks!

Comment: This works. To not draw the background on the webview you need : `[webView setDrawsBackground:NO];`